# AndroidTV based app does not appear in search results

Tags: android, android-tv

I have developed an app targeting AndroidTV devices, Google Chromecast in particular. The app is successfully uploaded to Google Play and in Developer Console the `App status` says `Production` - and indeed, I can see the app using its direct link to Google Play i.e. `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=`.

If I search the app through Google Play on a PC web browser - i can find it, but it says "This app is not available for any of your devices" even though I've signed in using the same account on my Chromecast device.

If I search the app through Google Play using a phone - the app isn't shown - which is expected since it is not targeted to touch screen devices.

If I search the app through my Chromecast device - **it is not in the results**, which led me to asking my question here.

Few weeks already passed since uploading so I'm excluding the time to index in search as a possible issue.

The app does not contain any ads.

The app is not in any of the `Testing` statuses.

The app's `App content` page is fully submitted, everything is green check-marked.

Additional info:

`Countries / regions` says 176/176.

`Device catalog` status says `Supported` for Google Chromecast Google TV.

`App availability` is set to `Published. New users can find and install your app`

`Managed Google Play` is set to `Turn off. Managed Google Play settings won't be available`

Some code:

**AndroidManifest**:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_logo"
        android:banner="@drawable/launcher_logo"
        android:logo="@drawable/launcher_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
            android:name=".BlankActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for an AndroidTV app to be available, first it has to be classified and reviewed as such.

These are the steps to opt in for a review:

1. In Developer Console, click on the app you want to opt in.
2. On the left side, go to Advanced Settings
3. Click on Release types
4. Click on the **+ Add release type** and choose AndroidTV

Follow the prompts and upload the required image assests, then wait for someone from Google to review your app. The review status will be send later to the developer email.

Comment: I did all those and got message from google that app is live but still can not see even after 2 hours